# How do I import multiple excel files and merge them using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, openpyxl

How do I import muleiple excel files and merge them using openpyxl
the code I have so far is this.....

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

def Test (filepath, yaml_sheetname):
    assumed_cell = "A1"
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/c1carpenter/Desktop/Test.xlsx')
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/c1carpenter/Desktop/Test2.xlsx')                             
    sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()

    if 'metadata' not in sheet_names:
    error_msg = "{0}'{1}' .".format(NON_WIZARD_XLSX_ERROR_PREFIX, filepath)
    raise ValueError(error_msg)

    yaml_sheet = wb[yaml_sheetname]
    yaml_string = yaml_sheet[assumed_cell].value

    print(yaml_string)
```

Comment: If you want to copy a worksheet between workbooks then you will have to copy everything cell by cell.

Comment: It would help if you edited the question to show some worked examples of how two or more of your files need to be merged. Show the input data, and what the output data should look like.